# Programming C dynamic table error storage size of `table' isn't known

Tags: c

I want to compile the program with a dynamic size of the table I tried `int Table[];` 
My program's

the compiler returns this message 4 C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Mes documents\TD4.c storage size of `table' aren't known?
I don't know storage? what is my fault

Comment: Your fault is that you don't know which programming language you use: is it C or C++? Please adjust your tags appropriately and/or name your documents the way you need it.

Comment: before, at the university, we use cpp extension to compile a c program .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, you can't declare an array with unknown size.

```
int Table[];
```

is simply not allowed.

Instead you can declare a pointer:

```
int *Table;
```

and dynamically allocate/reallocate using [malloc/realloc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) functions.

Comment: You can declare array in that case. `int table[100];` Note that it can't a variable like `N`. Variable length arrays are supported only after C99. But `N` can be defined `#define N 100`.

Answer (score 1):

When you a table you have to declare it's initial size: `int table[SIZE];`. When you don't know the table's size at compilation time (e.g. you read data from the user) you always can allocate memory in different way (size is a variable, not a constant):

`int* table = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size));`

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: Hmm... why? Could I do this in C++?

Comment: In C++ you have to. In C, [you must not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dynamic Table/array, you can do so using `malloc` function in C and using `new` operator in C++. You should deallocate the memory using `free` and `delete` depending on whether you use C or C++.

Comment: I can see that warning is thrown out from .cpp file. Thats why I am mentioning C++.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically define an array in that way. You must give it a storage size:

```
    int Table[43];
```

Another way would be to use malloc:

```
    int *Table = malloc (sizeof (int) * N);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        Table[i] = i;
```

Where N would be passed by some means. Don't forget to use `free()` on the array after.